# Setting with for local action script

Tags: github, github-actions

Is it possible to set with parameters not `process.env.message` for local scripts?

Getting error:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/message.yml (Line: n, Col: n): Unexpected value 'run' .github/workflows/message.yml (Line: n, Col: n): Required property is missing: uses
```

e.g.

**.github/scripts/action.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

import * as core from '@actions/core'

async function run() {
  if (core.getInput('message') !== 'must-message') {
    core.setFailed('message is invalid')
  }
}

run()
```

**./github/workflows/message.yml**

```
name: "message"
jobs:
  validate:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: check message
        run: .github/scripts/action.js
        with:
          message: 'must-message'
```

Comment: Yes, if you convert your script into a [composite run steps action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-run-steps-action).

Comment: @BenjaminW. So for scripts its only possible to set ENV vars?

Comment: Or you could provide them as command line parameters?

Comment: @BenjaminW. since I see you understand the issue. Could you post it as answer what you think is lightweight solution?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Node, but it looks like you could call your script with `.github/scripts/action.js 'must-message'` and then access the argument with `process.argv[1]` or so?